# NSTimer crashes

Tags: objective-c

I've been looking for an answer, and I nothing works.

I have a NSTimer as an attribute of the Appdelegate, this NSTimer should fire his action at anytime, even when the app is on the background(it's a localization app - so it can be running for ever)

This is the code:

```
if(conectar){
            self.myTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0
                                                            target:self
                                                          selector:@selector(abrirPresencia)
                                                          userInfo:nil
                                                           repeats:NO]retain];
        }
        else{
            self.myTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0
                                                    target:self
                                                  selector:@selector(cerrarPresencia)
                                                  userInfo:nil
                                                           repeats:NO]retain];
        }
```

After 10 seconds the app crashes, I have breakpoints in both methods and it doesnt stop, as if the method wasnt even called, instead of firing the method it crashes.

Here are the methods:

```
-(void)cerrarPresencia{
NSLog(@"SOY EL TIMERRRRR!!!! %@");
//[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateBackground
if (YES){
    [self.location stopUpdatingLocation];
    [self disconnect];

}
else{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ups!"
                                                        message:@"Según tu perfil querrías estar desconectado pero como lo estás usando hemos incluido este horario. Para cambiarlo sólo tienes que ir a editar perfil."
                                                       delegate:self 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];

    [alertView release];
}
```

}

```
-(void)abrirPresencia{
NSLog(@"SOY EL TIMERRRRR!!!! %@");
if (YES){
    [self.location stopUpdatingLocation];
    [self disconnect];

}
else{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ups!"
                                                        message:@"Según tu perfil querrías estar desconectado pero como lo estás usando hemos incluido este horario. Para cambiarlo sólo tienes que ir a editar perfil."
                                                       delegate:self 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];

    [alertView release];
}
```

}

And the property is:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSTimer *myTimer;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post those methods? What error is in the crash log?

Comment: If the methods you are calling have one (or more) arguments, you should add a colon : at the end of the selector. Could you do what @Vladimir asked and post the methods?

Comment: Most probably this is a SIGABRT. Try adding ":" in your selector names. Eg: (cerrarPresencia:)

Comment: can you also paste the property for the myTimer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"SOY EL TIMERRRRR!!!! %@");
```

Remember that compiler warning you got on this line that said

> warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Wformat,7]

?

Pay attention to those warnings. You're calling `NSLog` with an argument which includes a format specifier `%@`, and that makes it think there are going to be further arguments. If you don't pass those further arguments, the function still looks in the place it expects the argument to be, finds junk, and causes a crash.

Comment: That sir, is well spotted! @David Shaikh, try removing the %@ lines from both the methods and see what happens. If you still get a crash, please include the crash log.

Comment: Good lord! that was it! Thanks to everyone and specially @Josh Caswell

Answer (score 2):

The selector is wrong, it must be in this form:

`- (void) abrirPresencia:(NSTimer*)theTimer`

Also the selector needs to specify an argument with a trailing colon:
`selector:@selector(abrirPresencia)`

From the Apple API docs:

```
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats
```

The message to send to target when the timer fires. The selector must have the following signature:

```
- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer
```

Comment: I added the changes you suggested
-(void)cerrarPresencia:(NSTimer*)theTimer{
selector:@selector(cerrarPresencia:)

And I get the same error ....